# random_shuffle modifies shuffled objects (c++11)

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, shuffle

I have a vector with Tour objects and want to shuffle them. Fortunate there is a function `random_shuffle()`. I print the objects before and after the shuffling, however, one field of the objects is not shuffled at all.

The first thing to come to mind is that the copy or move constructor is incorrect. After using a cout in both constructors I found out that the move constructor is used. Strangely enough the constructors seems right to me.

The code and the move constructor are given below. Recall, only one field is incorrect after the shuffling, namely `d_penalty`. Can anyone help me solving this error?

```
std::vector<Tour> tours;
// Fill vector with 4 tour objects

std::cout << "Print vector\n";
for (Tour const &tour: tours)
  std::cout << tour << std::endl;

std::cout << "Shuffle\n";
std::random_shuffle(tours.begin(), tours.end());

std::cout << "Print vector\n";
for (Tour const &tour: tours)
  std::cout << tour << std::endl;
```

The move constructor is defined as follows,

```
#include "tour.ih"

/**
 * Move constructor
 */

Tour::Tour(Tour &&other)
:
  d_capacity(other.d_capacity),
  d_demand(other.d_demand),
  d_feasible(other.d_feasible),
  d_length(other.d_length),
  d_time(other.d_time),
  d_penalty(other.d_penalty),
  d_tour(std::move(other.d_tour))
{ 
  cout << "Tour moved\n";
}
```

The class is defined as follows,

```
class Tour
{
  // Current information about the tour
  int    d_capacity;    // Remaining capacity of the truck 
  int    d_demand;      // Total demand of all customers in the tour
  bool   d_feasible;    // Is the tour feasible in capacity
  double d_length;      // Length of the current tour
  double d_time;        // Driving time plus serving time
  double d_penalty;     // The penalty for infeasibility

  // The tour itself
  std::vector<City const *> d_tour;

  public:
    // Other functions

  private:
    // More functions
};
```

Comment: What about move assignment? Also, `random_shuffle` is deprecated in C++14 and removed in C++17; you should use `std::shuffle`.

Comment: Are you asking about `std::random_shuffle`? You don't have `using namespace std;` and you qualify all the other types in that namespace, so I'm confused.

Comment: @user2079303 Yes I meant `std::random_shuffle`. In the project I have used `using namespace std` but I added the std:: here for cleanliness and forgot one.

Comment: @T.C. I didn't know that the move assignment was necessary for this. Indeed I only had a constructor, a destructor, a copy constructor, a move constructor, and a copy assignment. I thought that this 5 where needed, however adding the move assignment indeed solves the problem! Is is usual to always add the move assignment operator if you have a move constructor? (If you want you can post this as short/simple answer)

Comment: I'm guessing there is a bug in your copy assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::random_shuffle` *swaps* the elements. The default swap, implemented by `std::swap`, uses both move construction and move assignment.

If you don't have a move assignment operator, then the copy assignment operator would be used instead. Since your move constructor does handle `d_penalty` correctly, it sounds like that your copy assignment operator isn't implemented properly.

In general, a class that can benefit from move semantics should have both a move constructor and a move assignment operator. Where possible, the special member function should be defined as `= default;`.

Also, `std::random_shuffle` is deprecated in C++14 and removed in C++17; you should use `std::shuffle` and a URNG in the `<random>` header such as `std::mt19937`.

Comment: Note that in MSVC2013, `=default` doesn't work with move assign/construct.  It apparently will work in 2015.